# IONIC ISSUE Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3-2

Tags: android, ionic-framework, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, ionic4

I am trying to build and emulate an android app using IONIC framework, but I am facing some issues after running ionic cordova build android.
Here are all the versions listed:

- OS: Windows 10 x64
- Ionic: 4.12.0
- Cordova: 8.1.2
- Gradle: 4.10.1

I also create a gradle.properties file in [project_name]\platforms\android where I specify the http and https settings for my proxy. The same I did in the gradle-wrapper.properties file.

> > ionic-v1 build [11:26:25] Invoking sass gulp task.
> >     cordova build android Android Studio project detected Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
> >     C:\Users\KAA1WA3\Desktop\ionic\todo\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js
> >     C:\Users\KAA1WA3\Desktop\ionic\todo
> >     ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\KAA1WA3\Desktop\androidSDK\androidSDK
> >     JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181 studio Starting a Gradle
> >     Daemon, 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for
> >     details
> >     Task :wrapper
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s 1 actionable task: 1 executed Subproject Path:
>   CordovaLib Subproject Path: app
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   >     Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3-2.
>   >      Required by:
>   >          project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.1
>   >          project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.1 >
>   >     com.android.tools.build:builder:3.0.1
>   >          project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.1 >
>   >     com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.0.1
>   >          project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.1 >

My build.gradle file:

```
/* Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
   or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
   distributed with this work for additional information
   regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
   to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
   "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
   with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
   software distributed under the License is distributed on an
   "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
   KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
   specific language governing permissions and limitations
   under the License.
*/

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter{url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"}
    }
    dependencies {

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter{url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"}
    }
    //This replaces project.properties w.r.t. build settings
    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="27.0.1" //String
      defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=27 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=27 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Share your app build.gradle

Comment: @RanjanKumar done!

Comment: I don't see you including kotlin plugin in your build.gradle

Comment: @RanjanKumar how to include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Example to include kotlin plugin.

app/build.gradle
-----------------
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}


build.gradle
------------
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```