# Sync failed when import kotlin to my submodules

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I try to import kotlin in my submodules:

project level

```
...
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
...
```

module level

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
...
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    ...
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}
```

And after i try to sync, i got this error:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@develop/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :libraries:Foundation.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

And the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.common.collect.UsingToStringOrdering.compare(UsingToStringOrdering.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.attributes.DefaultDisambiguationRuleChain$ExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultDisambiguationRuleChain.java:99)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.attributes.DefaultDisambiguationRuleChain$ExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultDisambiguationRuleChain.java:87)
        at org.gradle.internal.action.InstantiatingAction.execute(InstantiatingAction.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.attributes.DefaultDisambiguationRuleChain.execute(DefaultDisambiguationRuleChain.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.attributes.DefaultDisambiguationRuleChain.execute(DefaultDisambiguationRuleChain.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.attributes.DefaultAttributesSchema$MergedSchema.disambiguate(DefaultAttributesSchema.java:183)
        at org.gradle.internal.component.model.MultipleCandidateMatcher.disambiguateWithAttribute(MultipleCandidateMatcher.java:215)
        at org.gradle.internal.component.model.MultipleCandidateMatcher.disambiguateWithRequestedAttributes(MultipleCandidateMatcher.java:202)
        at org.gradle.internal.component.model.MultipleCandidateMatcher.disambiguateCompatibleCandidates(MultipleCandidateMatcher.java:192)
        at org.gradle.internal.component.model.MultipleCandidateMatcher.getMatches(MultipleCandidateMatcher.java:111)
        at org.gradle.internal.component.model.ComponentAttributeMatcher.match(ComponentAttributeMatcher.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.attributes.DefaultAttributesSchema$DefaultAttributeMatcher.matches(DefaultAttributesSchema.java:156)
        at org.gradle.internal.component.model.AttributeConfigurationSelector.selectConfigurationUsingAttributeMatching(AttributeConfigurationSelector.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.component.model.LocalComponentDependencyMetadata.selectConfigurations(LocalComponentDependencyMetadata.java:117)
        at org.gradle.internal.component.local.model.DslOriginDependencyMetadataWrapper.selectConfigurations(DslOriginDependencyMetadataWrapper.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.EdgeState.calculateTargetConfigurations(EdgeState.java:166)
        ... 105 more
```

My gradle version:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

I searched a lot but I can not find the reason and solution for the problem. Did anyone meet the same problem as me??

Comment: You need to tell us more about `:libraries:Foundation`

Comment: @shkschneider The foundation module is a submodule of my project. It depends on appcompat-v7, gson, glide and okhttpClient. Actually it is empty now. Thus I feel very confused.

Comment: @Aquarids, please check if you are including kotlin plugins in right way.                https://stackoverflow.com/a/55398104/4181904

Comment: You need to post the complete build.gradle of your app (referencing the Foundation module) and also the gradle from that module. Also the folder hierarchy, as it should be in `./Libraries/Foundation` from the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but I do not know why...

In my foundation module

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

and in my app module

```
buildTypes {
    ...
    test {
        ...
        matchingFallbacks = ['release', 'debug']
    }
}
```

after I remove 'debug' in matchingFallbacks or kotlin-plugin in foundation module, it works fine.